# What rules does OS X use for naming mounted volumes?

Tags: macos, mount

When I use [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) (a successor of TrueCrypt) to mount volumes on my filesystem, and I don't specify where it should mount them, the results are:

```
/Volumes/NO NAME
/Volumes/NO NAME 1
/Volumes/NO NAME 2
```

...and similar. I suspect these default paths don't come from VeraCrypt, but rather are set somewhere in OS X itself.

I ask because I'm trying to predict what other people's OS X installations will do, and I'm worried theirs are configured differently than mine. I'd like to be able to predict the mounted paths on other comps, and I'm getting reports of paths like:

```
/Volumes/Untitled
```

But I can't reproduce this.

**Questions**

1. Can anyone verify this is standard OS X behavior?
2. By what rules does OS X decide where volumes are mounted on the filesystem, especially what are the defaults and how are they set?
3. Is this question related to the unix or BSD ancestry of OS X?

**EDIT**

I'm really trying to understand why and when different volume labels are used (the "NO NAME" or "Untitled" part).

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but I usually see unnamed volumes mount as "NO NAME" when they are formatted as MS-DOS (FAT) and "Untitled" when they are formatted as HSS (or whatever format OS X Extended is).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, this is standard OSX behavior. If you have two identically named volumes, OSX will suffix 2-N with a digit in the filesystem (however, I don't believe they appear differently named on the desktop)
2. OSX mounts everything under `/Volumes/`. You can see what the interface is by running the `mount` command. Physical volumes are mounted in `/dev/diskXsY`, where X and Y are interface ID's.
3. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - you asked it in the Apple area.

Comment: how about the "NO NAME" part? sorry if my question wasn't clear...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - it's called NO NAME because it has no name and OSX needs to name it *something* to allow it to be accessed (you can't have a folder with literally no name).

Comment: Very true. But it could have called it "UNNAMED" or "Unknown" or just given it a number. I ask because I'm trying to predict what other people's OS X installations will do, and I'm worried theirs are configured differently than mine. I'd like to be able to predict the mounted paths on other comps.

Comment: Some Googling reveals that these volumes from TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt always mount with the name "NO NAME" -- so it's not just your install.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes this is standard behavior.
2. & 3. Are in part covered by what's quoted below from Mac OS X and iOS Internals To the Apple’s Core by Jonathan Levin published by ￼￼John Wiley & Sons, Inc.

> [image]

Other then the mount points defined in the Automounter master map and `/etc/fstab`, if present, all other mounts handled by OS X take place under `/Volumes/`.

Comment: Great, but I don't see any details on the name of the volume once mounted. Where does "NO NAME" come from? Can it be configured a/o does it vary?

Comment: @Chris, "NO NAME" is the volume label.

Comment: Ok, so it's the volume label. I don't know what that is. Where does it come from? Why might it vary?

Comment: @Chris, It can come from the actual volume label or the OS, it all depends on what's being mounted and how it was created and under what OS, how created and defaults vs choices made by the User when it was initially done.  As an example under Windows if one formatted a floppy diskette without providing a Label, then NO NAME was used by default and didn't appear in the GUI while being formatted but was reported from the command line.